# define variable in loop scope or should be out of scope?

Tags: javascript

I believed the variable should be out of the loop, so that define variable only once.

Like,

```
var target;
elementsArray.forEach(function(ele) {
    target = $('input[name=' + ele + ']');
    // do something with target
});
```

but, I read some JS coding recommendation, that said, the variable should be defined in the scope.

then should I use like this? ,

```
elementsArray.forEach(function(ele) {
    var target = $('input[name=' + ele + ']');
    // do something with target
});
```

It doesn't cost any if creating multiple new instance?

Comment: it depends on how you want to make use of the variable

Comment: It depends what you need to accomplish. You ask something what is better `-` or `+`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It only really matters if you're doing something with it outside of the loop.

1. Defining `target` outside of the loop will mean that after your loop has executed the last `$('input[name=' + ele + ']')` element hit by your loop will still be assigned to your `target` variable.
2. Defining `target` inside of the loop will mean that `target` will be *undefined* outside of the loop.

Comment: So, if the target will be used only in loop. then it's better define in the loop correct?, it doesn't cost if creating multiple new instance?

Comment: @Expertwannabe the performance hit for defining multiple times is completely negligible.

Answer (score 0):

> Both the `foreach` will behave differently. `forEach` creates new `scope`(*function level*) for each item in array..

For global variable, it will override the value for each iteration..for local, it will create new instance for each item.

If there are any `click events` are being handled in `forEach`, for `global` variable, it will always take last item into consideration as value is overwritten.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and you time!

Answer (score 0):

#### Both are not the same things

It is not just a loop, it is function being called inside a loop.

And each function has its own scope.

In the first example, target is visible to function enclosing this forEach loop, in the second example, target is only visible inside this function.